# Laravel 5.1 migrate database to hosted mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, artisan-migrate

How would I go about doing this (the title is the question), I've changed all my ENV files to my hosted mysql details. When i run php artisan migrate from composer I get the

> "denied username@localhost using password yes error".

I've changed the port and everything but I'm not sure what to do anymore and I'm 99% sure that the details are correct I've tried them multiple times

Comment: Are your files local and do you want them to connect to a remote database? If then, does your remote database have a remote access enabled config?

Comment: did you change your database.php details?

Comment: My files are corrently local do i need to upload them to the server first before running migrate..? please tell me its that simple

Comment: @PardeepPathania you dont need to as long as the ENV files are changed it uses the ENV files over the other values in database.php

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius i know that but you have to change the details as well, so try to change it.

Comment: you haven't changed the config of the database, if so, go to your project file then "app/config/database.php" then just change the database name to yours name. (in mysql array)

and after that run command php artisan config:clear

Comment: @PardeepPathania yes this didnt work for me I needed to upload the files and then i could just so 'php artisan migrate' through SSH

Answer (score 1):

You need check somethings:

- are credentials valid (username, password and host)?
- the database host is accessible by your application server?
- `.env` file is correctly configured or have some config hard coded in `app/config/database.php`?

To validade connection, you can try this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

About configuration and enviroments : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration

Comment: Thank you for this i love how detailed the answers are people give on this site keep up the good work! I figured out the answer to my question though